# Scala foldLeft performance 4x worse than for loop when working with floats

Tags: scala

Can someone with broader knowledge of the subject explain, why is

```
var acc = 0.0
for (i <- 0 until 100)
    acc += 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1)
```

over 4 times faster than

```
(0 until 100).foldLeft(0.0)({
    (d, i) => d + 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1)
})
```

I prefer the functional version, just don't quite understand the peformance hit. Any way to optimize this or maybe a `foldLeft` alternative?

Comment: Manipulation of mutable data will almost (if not) always be faster than immutable data structures, so it should be no surprise that the first example is faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First**, This is way too small of an example to get an accurate benchmark.  You can't really tell anything from these numbers.  You also have to control for things like JVM warm up, which will totally throw off any numbers you get.

That said, you can look at the source to see exactly how these things are implemented.  In particular, `Range`'s `foldLeft` is defined on `TraversableOnce`, which you can view [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L141):

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var result = z
  this foreach (x => result = op(result, x))
  result
}
```

As you can see, `foldLeft` is just delegating to `foreach`, which is exactly what the `for(...)` syntax resolves to.

In other words, they are actually doing the same thing.

The general rule is that you're probably not going to see a real difference performance-wise on anything like this unless you're doing an enormous number of calculations.  If it really is an issue, the fastest thing to do would be to use a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks. So using while would still be imperative then I take it?

Comment: Yeah, there's often an ugly/error-prone way to write stuff, but in nearly all cases, it's better to write cleaner, safer code.  You should only worry about these kinds of micro-optimizations when you really need to.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple recursive version:

```
@tailrec
final def rec(i:Int, max:Int, acc:Double): Double = 
  if (i == max) acc else rec(i+1, max, acc + 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1))
```

I ran these methods and a recursive one through Calipher, using this [simple Scala SBT benchmarking template](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-benchmarking-template), with sizes of 100, 1000, ..., 10000000. Here are the results:

```
[info]   length benchmark        ns linear runtime
[info]      100       For       893 =
[info]      100  FoldLeft      1447 =
[info]      100       Rec       888 =
[info]     1000       For     10540 =
[info]     1000  FoldLeft     20322 =
[info]     1000       Rec     11048 =
[info]    10000       For    115499 =
[info]    10000  FoldLeft    255171 =
[info]    10000       Rec    116690 =
[info]   100000       For   1268198 =
[info]   100000  FoldLeft   2223178 =
[info]   100000       Rec   1114504 =
[info]  1000000       For  11985576 =
[info]  1000000  FoldLeft  23916076 ==
[info]  1000000       Rec  11993123 =
[info] 10000000       For 114804171 ==============
[info] 10000000  FoldLeft 244991000 ==============================
[info] 10000000       Rec 119422600 ==============
```

Notice the functional, non-mutating, recursive version is just about as fast as the for loop (tail recursion for the win). Also, notice that the foldLeft version is about twice as slow.

Comment: Actually in my particular case your solution is up to 40% faster than the for loop. Well done and thanks.